# Touchpad keeps working while typing even after disabling the option in configuration

Tags: 10.10, touchpad, samsung

My problem is that touchpad in my Samsung R580 keeps working while I'm typing. I already  disabled the option in the mouse configuration. If you need more info, just ask. Thank you for any help!

Comment: After checking to make sure the option is definitely selected, file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the touchpad while typing can be achieved through "syndaemon." Here are the instructions from the Arch Linux Wiki, which I assume will almost certainly work on Ubuntu:

To start syndaemon you need to use Gnome's Startup Applications Preferences program. Login to Gnome and go to System > Preferences > Startup Applications. In the Startup Programs tab click the Add button. Name the Startup Program whatever you like and input any comments you like (or leave this field blank). In the command field add:

```
syndaemon -t -k -i 2 -d &
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :/ now when I type, cursor disappears, but when I touch the touchpad (while typing) it appears and it's "fully" active :/